# wp_insert_post_data: Limit number of Page but Post get affected

Tags: posts

I want to limit Page creation to be 3, without interfering other post type like Post. I'm using below function:

```
  function set_post_to_draft_page_only( $data, $postarr ) {
    if($data['post_type'] == 'page') {

      if( wp_count_posts('page')->publish > 2 ) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
      }
      return $data;
    }
  }
  add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'set_post_to_draft_page_only', 99, 2 );
```

The function above works for Page but it will interfere Post (Add New Post will show error). So I added `return $data;` to exclude Post:

```
  function set_post_to_draft_page_only( $data, $postarr ) {
    if($data['post_type'] == 'page') {

      if( wp_count_posts('page')->publish > 2 ) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
      }
      return $data;
    }
    if($data['post_type'] == 'post') {          // without this part, Add New Post will show error
      return $data;
    }
  }
  add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'set_post_to_draft_page_only', 99, 2 );
```

This is not good way because if I added more post type, I need to manually add more exception.

So what is the better way to only limit Page creation without interfering other post type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest one slight change to your logic as follows:

```
function set_post_to_draft_page_only( $data, $postarr ) {
    if($data['post_type'] == 'page') {

      if( wp_count_posts('page')->publish > 2 ) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
      }
    }
    return $data;
  }
  add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'set_post_to_draft_page_only', 99, 2 );
```

You were not returning `$data` if post type was anything other than 'page'.